# Local infeasibility in MATLAB

Tags: gekko

I need help with a dynamic optimization problem that consist in a consumed energy optimization of a UAV with this optimal control problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG0Mk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYw9M.png)

My code is this

Ecuations:

```
Parameters
tf

#Velocidad de rotores rad/s
#Las condiciones iniciales permiten igualar la acción de la gravedad
#Se tomo 4000rad/s como la velocidad maxima de los rotores
w1 = 912.32, >=0, <=3000
w2 = 912.32, >=0, <=3000
w3 = 912.32, >=0, <=3000
w4 = 912.32, >=0, <=3000
t1 = 0, >=0
t2 = 0, >=0
t3 = 0, >=0
t4 = 0, >=0

Constants
!----------------COEFICIENTES DEL MODELO-----------------!
#Gravedad
g = 9.81 !m/s^2
pi = 3.14159265359

#Motor Coefficients
 J = 4.1904e-5 !kg*m^2
 kt = 0.0104e-3 !N*m/A
 kv = 96.342 !rad/s/volt
 Dv = 0.2e-3 !N*m*s/rad
 R = 0.2 !Ohms

#Battery parameters
 Q = 1.55 !Ah
 Rint = 0.02 !Ohms
 E0 = 1.24 !volt
 K = 2.92e-3 !volt
 A = 0.156
 B =2.35

#Quadrotor parameters
  l = 0.175 !m
  m = 1.3 !kg
  Ix = 0.081 !kg*m^2
  Iy = 0.081 !kg*m^2
  Iz = 0.142 !kg*m^2
  kb = 3.8305e-6 !N/rad/s
  ktau = 2.2518e-8 !(N*m)/rad/s

#Parametrizacion del polinomio
  a1 = -1.72e-5
  a2 = 1.95e-5
  a3 = -6.98e-6
  a4 = 4.09e-7
  b1 = 0.014
  b2 = -0.0157
  b3 = 5.656e-3
  b4 = -3.908e-4
  c1 = -0.8796
  c2 = 0.3385
  c3 = 0.2890
  c4 = 0.1626

Variables
!------------------CONDICONES INICIALES------------------!
 x = 0
 xp = 0
 y = 0
 yp = 0
 z = 0
 zp = 0
 pitch = 0, >=-pi/2, <=pi/2   !theta - restricciones
 pitchp = 0
 roll = 0, >=-pi/2, <=pi/2    !phi - restricciones
 rollp = 0
 yaw = 0                      !psi
 yawp = 0%, >=-200/180, <=200/180

#Función objetivo
  of = 0 !condición inicial de la función objetivo
Intermediates

#Motor 1
  aw1 = a1*w1^2 + b1*w1 + c1
  bw1 = a2*w1^2 + b2*w1 + c2
  cw1 = a3*w1^2 + b3*w1 + c3
  dw1 = a4*w1^2 + b4*w1 + c4
#Motor 2
  aw2 = a1*w2^2 + b1*w2 + c1
  bw2 = a2*w2^2 + b2*w2 + c2
  cw2 = a3*w2^2 + b3*w2 + c3
  dw2 = a4*w2^2 + b4*w2 + c4 
#Motor 3
  aw3 = a1*w3^2 + b1*w3 + c1
  bw3 = a2*w3^2 + b2*w3 + c2
  cw3 = a3*w3^2 + b3*w3 + c3
  dw3 = a4*w3^2 + b4*w3 + c4
#Motor 4
  aw4 = a1*w4^2 + b1*w4 + c1
  bw4 = a2*w4^2 + b2*w4 + c2
  cw4 = a3*w4^2 + b3*w4 + c3
  dw4 = a4*w4^2 + b4*w4 + c4
#frj(wj(t),Tj(t))
  fr1=aw1*t1^3 + bw1*t1^2 + cw1*t1 + dw1
  fr2=aw2*t2^3 + bw2*t2^2 + cw2*t2 + dw2
  fr3=aw3*t3^3 + bw3*t3^2 + cw3*t3 + dw3
  fr4=aw4*t4^3 + bw4*t4^2 + cw4*t4 + dw4
!---------------------CONTROL INPUTS---------------------!
  T = kb * (w1^2 + w2^2 + w3^2 + w4^2)
  u1 = kb * (w2^2 - w4^2)
  u2 = kb * (w3^2 - w1^2)
  u3 = ktau * (w1^2 - w2^2 + w3^2 - w4^2)
  wline = w1 - w2 + w3 - w4
!-------------------ENERGIA POR ROTOR--------------------!
  Ec1 = ((J*$w1 + ktau*w1^2 + Dv*w1)/fr1)*w1
  Ec2 = ((J*$w2 + ktau*w2^2 + Dv*w2)/fr2)*w2
  Ec3 = ((J*$w3 + ktau*w3^2 + Dv*w3)/fr3)*w3
  Ec4 = ((J*$w4 + ktau*w4^2 + Dv*w4)/fr4)*w4
  Ectotal = Ec1 + Ec2 + Ec3 + Ec4
Equations
!---------------MINIMIZAR FUNCIÓN OBJETIVO---------------!
  minimize tf * of
!-----------------RELACION DE VARIABLES------------------!
  xp = $x
  yp = $y
  zp = $z
  pitchp = $pitch
  rollp = $roll
  yawp = $yaw
!-----------------CONDICONES DE FRONTERA-----------------!
#Condiciones finales del modelo
  tf * x = 4
  tf * y = 5
  tf * z = 6
  tf * xp = 0
  tf * yp = 0
  tf * zp = 0
  tf * roll = 0
  tf * pitch = 0
  tf * yaw = 0
!-----------------TORQUE DE LOS MOTORES------------------!
  t1 = J*$w1 + ktau*w1^2 + Dv*w1
  t2 = J*$w2 + ktau*w2^2 + Dv*w2
  t3 = J*$w3 + ktau*w3^2 + Dv*w3
  t4 = J*$w4 + ktau*w4^2 + Dv*w4
!------------------------SUJETO A------------------------!
#Modelo aerodinámico del UAV
  m*$xp = (cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*cos(yaw) + sin(roll)*sin(yaw))*T
  m*$yp = (cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*sin(yaw) - sin(roll)*cos(yaw))*T
  m*$zp = (cos(roll)*cos(pitch))*T-m*g
  Ix*$rollp = ((Iy - Iz)*pitchp*yawp + J*pitchp*wline + l*u1)
  Iy*$pitchp = ((Iz - Ix)*rollp*yawp - J*rollp*wline + l*u2)
  Iz*$yawp = ((Ix - Iy)*rollp*pitchp + u3)
!--------------------FUNCIÓN OBJETIVO--------------------!
  $of = Ectotal
```

MATLAB:

```
clear all; close all; clc

server = 'http://127.0.0.1';
app = 'traj_optima';

addpath('C:/Program Files/MATLAB/apm_matlab_v0.7.2/apm')
apm(server,app,'clear all');
apm_load(server,app,'ecuaciones_mod.apm');
csv_load(server,app,'tiempo2.csv');

apm_option(server,app,'apm.max_iter',200);
apm_option(server,app,'nlc.nodes',3);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.rtol',1);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.otol',1);
apm_option(server,app,'nlc.solver',3);
apm_option(server,app,'nlc.imode',6);
apm_option(server,app,'nlc.mv_type',1);


costo=1e-5;%1e-5
%VARIABLES CONTROLADAS
%Velocidades angulares
apm_info(server,app,'MV','w1');
apm_option(server,app,'w1.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','w2');
apm_option(server,app,'w2.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','w3'); 
apm_option(server,app,'w3.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','w4');
apm_option(server,app,'w4.status',1);

% Torques
apm_info(server,app,'MV','t1');
apm_option(server,app,'t1.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','t2');
apm_option(server,app,'t2.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','t3');
apm_option(server,app,'t3.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','t4');
apm_option(server,app,'t4.status',1);

%Salida
output = apm(server,app,'solve');
disp(output)
y = apm_sol(server,app); 
z = y.x;
```

tiempo2.csv

```
time,tf
0,0
0.001,0
0.2,0
0.4,0
0.6,0
0.8,0
1,0
1.2,0
1.4,0
1.6,0
1.8,0
2,0
2.2,0
2.4,0
2.6,0
2.8,0
3,0
3.2,0
3.4,0
3.6,0
3.8,0
4,0
4.2,0
4.4,0
4.6,0
4.8,0
5,0
5.2,0
5.4,0
5.6,0
5.8,0
6,0
6.2,0
6.4,0
6.6,0
6.8,0  
7,0
7.2,0
7.4,0
7.6,0
7.8,0
8,0
8.2,0
8.4,0 
8.6,0
8.8,0
9,0
9.2,0
9.4,0
9.6,0
9.8,0
10,1
```

Finally the answer obtained is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ungAG.png)

I need help with this local infeasibility problem, please.

Comment: Do you have any information on `tiempo2.csv`, the time points for your problem?

Comment: Yes, I have this information in a .csv with a time of 0 to 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The infeasible solution is caused by the terminal constraints:

```
  tf * z = 4
  tf * z = 5
  tf * z = 6
```

When `tf=0`, the constraints are evaluated to `0=4`, `0=5`, `0=6` and the solver reports that these can not be satisfied by the solver. Instead, you can pose the constraints as:

```
  tf * (x-4) = 0
  tf * (y-5) = 0
  tf * (z-6) = 0
```

That way, the constraint is valid when `tf=0` and when `tf=1` at the final time. A potential better way yet is to convert the terminal constraints to objective terms with `f=1000` such as:

```
  minimize f*tf*((x-4)^2 + (y-5)^2 + (z-6)^2)
  minimize f*tf*(xp^2 + yp^2 + zp^2)
  minimize f*tf*(roll^2 + pitch^2 + yaw^2)
```

That way, the optimizer won't report an infeasible solution if it can't reach the terminal constraints as [discussed in the pendulum problem](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/InvertedPendulum). I made a few other modifications to your model and script to achieve a successful solution. Here is a summary:

- Converted terminal constraints to objective function (soft constraints)
- Parameters `t1`-`t4` should be variables
- Fixed degree of freedom issue by making `w1`-`w4` variables and `w1p`-`w4p` variables. `w1`-`w4` are differential states.
- Added constraints to `w1p`-`w4p` between -10 and 10 to help the solver converge
- Added initialization step to simulate the model before optimizing. There are more details on initialization strategies in this paper: Safdarnejad, S.M., Hedengren, J.D., Lewis, N.R., Haseltine, E., [Initialization Strategies for Optimization of Dynamic Systems](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098135415001179), Computers and Chemical Engineering, 2015, Vol. 78, pp. 39-50, DOI: 10.1016/j.compchemeng.2015.04.016

**Model**

```py
Parameters
tf

 w1p = 0 > -10 < 10
 w2p = 0 > -10 < 10
 w3p = 0 > -10 < 10
 w4p = 0 > -10 < 10


Constants
!----------------COEFICIENTES DEL MODELO-----------------!
#Gravedad
g = 9.81 !m/s^2
pi = 3.14159265359

#Motor Coefficients
 J = 4.1904e-5 !kg*m^2
 kt = 0.0104e-3 !N*m/A
 kv = 96.342 !rad/s/volt
 Dv = 0.2e-3 !N*m*s/rad
 R = 0.2 !Ohms

#Battery parameters
 Q = 1.55 !Ah
 Rint = 0.02 !Ohms
 E0 = 1.24 !volt
 K = 2.92e-3 !volt
 A = 0.156
 B =2.35

#Quadrotor parameters
  l = 0.175 !m
  m = 1.3 !kg
  Ix = 0.081 !kg*m^2
  Iy = 0.081 !kg*m^2
  Iz = 0.142 !kg*m^2
  kb = 3.8305e-6 !N/rad/s
  ktau = 2.2518e-8 !(N*m)/rad/s

#Parametrizacion del polinomio
  a1 = -1.72e-5
  a2 = 1.95e-5
  a3 = -6.98e-6
  a4 = 4.09e-7
  b1 = 0.014
  b2 = -0.0157
  b3 = 5.656e-3
  b4 = -3.908e-4
  c1 = -0.8796
  c2 = 0.3385
  c3 = 0.2890
  c4 = 0.1626

Variables
!------------------CONDICONES INICIALES------------------!
 x = 0
 xp = 0
 y = 0
 yp = 0
 z = 0
 zp = 0
 pitch = 0, >=-pi/2, <=pi/2   !theta - restricciones
 pitchp = 0
 roll = 0, >=-pi/2, <=pi/2    !phi - restricciones
 rollp = 0
 yaw = 0                      !psi
 yawp = 0  %, >=-200/180, <=200/180

#Velocidad de rotores rad/s
#Las condiciones iniciales permiten igualar la acción de la gravedad
#Se tomo 4000rad/s como la velocidad maxima de los rotores
w1 = 912.32, >=0, <=3000
w2 = 912.32, >=0, <=3000
w3 = 912.32, >=0, <=3000
w4 = 912.32, >=0, <=3000

 t1 = 0, >=0
 t2 = 0, >=0
 t3 = 0, >=0
 t4 = 0, >=0

#Función objetivo
  of = 0 !condición inicial de la función objetivo
Intermediates

#Motor 1
  aw1 = a1*w1^2 + b1*w1 + c1
  bw1 = a2*w1^2 + b2*w1 + c2
  cw1 = a3*w1^2 + b3*w1 + c3
  dw1 = a4*w1^2 + b4*w1 + c4
#Motor 2
  aw2 = a1*w2^2 + b1*w2 + c1
  bw2 = a2*w2^2 + b2*w2 + c2
  cw2 = a3*w2^2 + b3*w2 + c3
  dw2 = a4*w2^2 + b4*w2 + c4 
#Motor 3
  aw3 = a1*w3^2 + b1*w3 + c1
  bw3 = a2*w3^2 + b2*w3 + c2
  cw3 = a3*w3^2 + b3*w3 + c3
  dw3 = a4*w3^2 + b4*w3 + c4
#Motor 4
  aw4 = a1*w4^2 + b1*w4 + c1
  bw4 = a2*w4^2 + b2*w4 + c2
  cw4 = a3*w4^2 + b3*w4 + c3
  dw4 = a4*w4^2 + b4*w4 + c4
#frj(wj(t),Tj(t))
  fr1=aw1*t1^3 + bw1*t1^2 + cw1*t1 + dw1
  fr2=aw2*t2^3 + bw2*t2^2 + cw2*t2 + dw2
  fr3=aw3*t3^3 + bw3*t3^2 + cw3*t3 + dw3
  fr4=aw4*t4^3 + bw4*t4^2 + cw4*t4 + dw4
!---------------------CONTROL INPUTS---------------------!
  T = kb * (w1^2 + w2^2 + w3^2 + w4^2)
  u1 = kb * (w2^2 - w4^2)
  u2 = kb * (w3^2 - w1^2)
  u3 = ktau * (w1^2 - w2^2 + w3^2 - w4^2)
  wline = w1 - w2 + w3 - w4
!-------------------ENERGIA POR ROTOR--------------------!
  Ec1 = ((J*$w1 + ktau*w1^2 + Dv*w1)/fr1)*w1
  Ec2 = ((J*$w2 + ktau*w2^2 + Dv*w2)/fr2)*w2
  Ec3 = ((J*$w3 + ktau*w3^2 + Dv*w3)/fr3)*w3
  Ec4 = ((J*$w4 + ktau*w4^2 + Dv*w4)/fr4)*w4
  Ectotal = Ec1 + Ec2 + Ec3 + Ec4

! scaling factor for terminal constraint
  f = 1000

Equations
!---------------MINIMIZAR FUNCIÓN OBJETIVO---------------!
  minimize tf * of
!-----------------RELACION DE VARIABLES------------------!
  xp = $x
  yp = $y
  zp = $z
  pitchp = $pitch
  rollp = $roll
  yawp = $yaw

  w1p = $w1
  w2p = $w2
  w3p = $w3
  w4p = $w4
!-----------------CONDICONES DE FRONTERA-----------------!
#Condiciones finales del modelo
  #tf * (x-4) = 0
  #tf * (y-5) = 0
  #tf * (z-6) = 0
  #tf * xp = 0
  #tf * yp = 0
  #tf * zp = 0
  #tf * roll = 0
  #tf * pitch = 0
  #tf * yaw = 0

  minimize f*tf*((x-4)^2 + (y-5)^2 + (z-6)^2)
  minimize f*tf*(xp^2 + yp^2 + zp^2)
  minimize f*tf*(roll^2 + pitch^2 + yaw^2)
!-----------------TORQUE DE LOS MOTORES------------------!
  t1 = J*w1p + ktau*w1^2 + Dv*w1
  t2 = J*w2p + ktau*w2^2 + Dv*w2
  t3 = J*w3p + ktau*w3^2 + Dv*w3
  t4 = J*w4p + ktau*w4^2 + Dv*w4
!------------------------SUJETO A------------------------!
#Modelo aerodinámico del UAV
  m*$xp = (cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*cos(yaw) + sin(roll)*sin(yaw))*T
  m*$yp = (cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*sin(yaw) - sin(roll)*cos(yaw))*T
  m*$zp = (cos(roll)*cos(pitch))*T-m*g
  Ix*$rollp = ((Iy - Iz)*pitchp*yawp + J*pitchp*wline + l*u1)
  Iy*$pitchp = ((Iz - Ix)*rollp*yawp - J*rollp*wline + l*u2)
  Iz*$yawp = ((Ix - Iy)*rollp*pitchp + u3)
!--------------------FUNCIÓN OBJETIVO--------------------!
  $of = Ectotal
```

**MATLAB Script**

```matlab
clear all; close all; clc

server = 'http://byu.apmonitor.com';
app = 'traj_optima';

addpath('apm')
apm(server,app,'clear all');
apm_load(server,app,'ecuaciones_mod.apm');
csv_load(server,app,'tiempo2.csv');

apm_option(server,app,'apm.max_iter',1000);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.nodes',3);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.rtol',1e-6);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.otol',1e-6);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.solver',3);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.imode',6);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.mv_type',1);


costo=1e-5;%1e-5
%VARIABLES CONTROLADAS
%Velocidades angulares
apm_info(server,app,'MV','w1p');
apm_option(server,app,'w1p.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','w2p');
apm_option(server,app,'w2p.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','w3p'); 
apm_option(server,app,'w3p.status',1);
apm_info(server,app,'MV','w4p');
apm_option(server,app,'w4p.status',1);

%Salida
disp('')
disp('------------- Initialize ----------------')
apm_option(server,app,'apm.coldstart',1);
output = apm(server,app,'solve');
disp(output)

disp('')
disp('-------------- Optimize -----------------')
apm_option(server,app,'apm.time_shift',0);
apm_option(server,app,'apm.coldstart',0);
output = apm(server,app,'solve');
disp(output)
y = apm_sol(server,app); 
z = y.x;
```

This gives a successful solution but the terminal constraints are not met. The solver optimizes the use of `w1p`-`w4p` to minimize the objective but there is no solution that makes it to the terminal constraints.

```
 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is    50477.4537378181     

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :    3.06940000000759      sec
 Objective      :    50477.4537378181     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

As a next step, I recommend that you increase the number of time points or [allow the final time to change](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MinimizeFinalTime) to meet the terminal constraints. You may also want to consider switching to [Python Gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that uses the same underlying engine as APM MATLAB. In this case, the modeling language is fully integrated with Python.